# update_or_create not updating/creating objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I found out that django 1.7 supports now update_or_create() method in queryset.
But when I try it, it is not working. There is no object created when I try this:

**models.py**

```
 class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

 class Model2(models.Model)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model1, null=True, blank=True) 
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
 def ModelUpdate(request)
     model1 = get_object_or_404(Model1, pk=request.POST['lid'])
     model1.status =2
     model1.save()

     #based on the model1, we want to create or update model2 
     datadict ={'field1' : 1, 'field2':2,}
     model2, created = Model2.objects.update_or_create(model=model1,
                                                       defaults=datadict) 
     if created:
         print('model2 obj created') #for checking purpose
    else: 
         print('model2 obj not created')

    return render(request,'updated.html', {'update':'updated'})
```

I can see the message *model2 obj created* but the object was not saved in the database. What could be the problem?

## **UPDATE**

Turns out it was my mistake. In the Model2, I defined the save method without returning  `super(Model2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`
That's why it didn't save the objects.

Comment: How are you verifying that the object was created?

Comment: From their [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) The `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created. Also, I looked into the database of Model2, no recorded was added.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you verifying in the wrong way, because I created project with your models and everything works fine.
In my case I'm verifying that object was created/updated with `objects.get()` and printing values:

```
In [1]: from app1 import models

In [2]: m1 = models.Model1.objects.create(name=1, status=1)

In [3]: m1
Out[3]: <Model1: Model1 object>

In [4]: datadict ={'field1' : 1, 'field2':2,}

In [6]: model2, created = models.Model2.objects.update_or_create(model=m1, defaults=datadict)

In [7]: model2, created
Out[7]: (<Model2: Model2 object>, True)

In [8]: models.Model2.objects.get().field1, models.Model2.objects.get().field2
Out[8]: (u'1', u'2')

In [9]: datadict ={'field1' : 3, 'field2':4}

In [10]: model2, created = models.Model2.objects.update_or_create(model=m1, defaults=datadict)

In [11]: model2, created
Out[11]: (<Model2: Model2 object>, False)

In [12]: models.Model2.objects.get().field1, models.Model2.objects.get().field2
Out[12]: (u'3', u'4')
```

and

```
In [13]: models.Model2.objects.get().model.id
Out[13]: 1

In [14]: models.Model1.objects.get().id
Out[14]: 1
```

Comment: But in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), it says 'created' is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created. So, i guess when it is True means the object is created. I didn't use `objects.get()` to check, I looked directly in the database model2 table. But no object was created. Oh..yes, I just upgrade from 1.6.5, is this upgrade have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yes, boolean `created` means that object was created. As you can see in the first time it was `true`, but in the next `false`, so it works properly. I can assume you didn't update db connection, where you looked in it. Another thing you can do - open database logs with `tail -f` and see what happens there. I don't think that this is upgrade issue.